# installing turtlebot for kinetic

Tags: turtlebot, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone ...

I'm trying to install Turtlebot for kinetic [link text](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot/Tutorials/indigo/Turtlebot%20Installation)

I changed all 'indigo' words to 'kinetic' after I did that I've this problem

E: Unable to locate package ros-kinetic-rocon-remocon

E: Unable to locate package ros-kinetic-rocon-qt-library

Can Anyone help me in solving this problem ..?

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249348/installing-turtlebot-for-kinetic/) by [jafar_abdi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25259/jafar_abdi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 221 on 2016-12-04

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jafar_abdi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25259/jafar_abdi/) on 2016-12-05**:
can anyone help me ..? :(

**Comment by [anonymous28838](https://answers.ros.org/users/28838/anonymous28838/) on 2016-12-18**:
I am having the same issue

**Comment by [momar82](https://answers.ros.org/users/14996/momar82/) on 2017-01-28**:
I do the same, I dont think you need this two application then don't install them :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey!!

Sorry this may be quite late, however I used this link in another ROS Answer in order to install Turtlebot with ROS-Kinetic. Atleast the install was successful.

https://answers.ros.org/question/246015/installing-turtlebot-on-ros-kinetic/

Cheers!

---

Originally posted by [aaditya_saraiya](https://answers.ros.org/users/31473/aaditya_saraiya/) with karma: 105 on 2017-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got everything up and running with these scripts: https://bitbucket.org/damienjadeduff/456_kinetic_turtlebot/src/b8eacebf174b?at=master

---

Originally posted by [vegetish](https://answers.ros.org/users/29570/vegetish/) with karma: 21 on 2017-03-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vegetish](https://answers.ros.org/users/29570/vegetish/) on 2017-03-05**:
Albeit some packages not working, like the dashboard.